# Rest API works in Google Rest Client but not in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cors

Rest API works in Google Rest Client but in AngularJS their is a CORS issue. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

CORS doesn't apply to the client because it isn't try to do the request from another website - it's doing it from your computer. But when you do it on your site using AngularJS - then you encounter the CORS issue.

Comment: How is Google Rest API sending their request to avoid the CORS issue? I've read so many different ways to try and solve the issue but not a standard one so I tried it in Goggle Rest API and that's when i saw it worked for them.

Comment: Sorry, just to make sure I'm on the right page with you - the Google REST client you are using is the Chrome Extension? Or something else?

Comment: Chrome Extensions are allowed to send and received data from remote servers. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: Gotcha, that makes me feel a lot better. Their needs to be a standard practice to this CORS issue because it waste a lot of development time.

Comment: Well - forgive me if I'm mistaken but I think maybe you're not quite seeing the difference between using the Chrome extension and trying to do the same call from inside a website. There's a big difference in the sense that CORS is meant to prevent REST calls between *websites* - but when you use the Chrome extension, you're making a call between your computer and a website (as opposed to two websites).

Comment: Your right, I wasn't clear on that. I was thinking the Google Chrome extension was implementing something to bypass CORS and I wanted to know what that was. Thank you for clarifying that for me.

Comment: Okay great. Good luck with your project